# Passing MSI properties to sqlstring

Tags: sql, wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

Hello I am trying to pass an `MSI` property to `Sqlstring` .

Below is my code . The property `GROUP` is set by `MSI` in the beginning and I need to pass the same to this `Sql Query` . I have tried replacing `[ and ]` with `[\[] and [\]]` as I read in one of the answers but i am still getting an the below error while I run the `MSI` . I am new to `WIX` any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGpmG.png)

```
<sql:SqlString Id="SuperUser" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ContinueOnError="no"  
SQL="IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Interface].[dbo].[user] A WHERE A.default_user = 1)
BEGIN

       INSERT INTO [Interface].[dbo].[user](staff_id, staff_name, status, default_user)
       VALUES('ab', 'ab', 'A', 1)

       INSERT INTO [Interface].[dbo].[rights](staff_id, role, role_n, name, enable)
       VALUES('ab', 6, 'admin', '[GROUP]', 'E')
END"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an MSI error, this is a SQL error. Read the description. "Incorrect syntax error near '('. I'm counting up your parenthesis in your statement and it looks like you're missing a closing ')'

Comment: There are 5 opening and 5 closing parenthesis and the same script works fine when executed independently

Comment: Ah, ok. I think it was a scroll issue on my part. The error still remains as an SQL error though.